# about local variables in a function (c++)

Tags: c++, local-variables

Here is my code :

```
void AjoutNoeudHydro(vector< NoeudHydro<PTNoeud> >* SysHydro,
                     PTNoeud NdSR,
                     char typeNd, int temps, int TabEqui[])
{
    NoeudHydro<PTNoeud> NdHydroAAjouter(NdSR,SysHydro->size(),typeNd,temps);

    //Relation Pere-Fils
    NdHydroAAjouter.SetPere(SysHydro->at(TabEqui[NdSR->prec->num]));
    SysHydro->at(TabEqui[NdSR->prec->num]).SetFils(NdHydroAAjouter);

    //Equivalences
    TabEqui[NdSR->num]=NdHydroAAjouter.GetNumero();

    //Ajout dans le vecteur
    SysHydro->push_back(NdHydroAAjouter);
    // delete NdHydroAAjouter;
}
```

What I actually do, is creating a new object of type `NoeudHydro<PTNoeud>`, doing some accommodations, and adding it to the vector `SysHydro` which is passed as argument of the function.
But I am absolutely not sure of what I'm doing.
When the function is done, the object I created is erased right ? It is a variable local of the function ? So does the vector will save that object ?

Comment: When the function is done the object created in the function is destroyed **but** it has been copied into the vector, the vector's copy is not destroyed (until it is erased from the vector). In other words your code looks correct to me.

Comment: Please provide [mre]. For example: Does `SetFils` store the pointer to the variable? Or does it store it as a value (i.e. a copy of it)?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius it stores the pointer : 
{

template <typename T>
void NoeudHydro<T>::SetFils(NoeudHydro& NdFils){
    this->Fils.push_back(&NdFils);
}
And you are pointing something that I think is my problem

Comment: @Taendyr In that case please provide manufactured [mre].

Comment: `SetFils(NdHydroAAjouter)` You're creating a parent-child relation here, if I'm translating correctly. But `NdHydroAAjouter` will go out of scope, and only a **copy** of `NdHydroAAjouter` survives in the vector. Will the parent of `NdHydroAAjouter` be aware of this copy? It might be better to immediately put `NdHydroAAjouter` in the vector , and then use `SysHydro.back()` instead of `NdHydroAAjouter`.

Comment: Yes, this what I realised thanks to Algirdas, and changed it the way you said. It now works . (And sorry for frenglish in the code)

Answer (score 0):

`NdHydroAAjouter` is a local variable and as this it will be destructed when the function returns.

Your `SysHydro->push_back(NdHydroAAjouter);` will store a copy of `NdHydroAAjouter` in `SysHydro`. This copy will still exist when your function returns.

All in all your question sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Yes it is. But I wanted first to be sure to understand what I asked